# Limit data rate of specific app (to avoid HD stream, for instance)

Tags: settings, 9.0-pie, mobile-data, data-connection, streaming

My data plan is decent, but not huge (2GB per month). Say that I want to watch a livestream on some app: I have no control over the data rate this app is getting. Since the cellular connection is good, the stream will default to HD quality. I want to manually restrict the data rate that a particular app is getting, since I'm totally fine watching a low-quality livestream, so that I can save my data. There are no livestream settings, but I know for a fact that the livestream will switch to lower quality video in case of limited bandwidth, since I have watched it when connected to some slow wi-fi hotspot.

My question: Is there a (developer) setting, or some app, that allows me to manually set a maximum data rate/bandwith that a SPECIFIC app is getting?

Most other questions on the stack seems to talk only about the data rate of the whole device ([Is there a ways to set data speed limit in android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55851/is-there-a-ways-to-set-data-speed-limit-in-android/55855#55855)) or are about stopping a specific app (using firewall) after it has consumed X amount of data ([How to limit data usage of individual apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29334/how-to-limit-data-usage-of-individual-apps)), and these questions seem to be a bit outdated as well.

I'm running Android 9, LineageOS 16, on a OnePlus A5010.

Thanks, cheers!

PS: I am aware I could select a lower speed "Prefered Network Type", such as GSM or 3G instead of LTE, but that seems to be a bit of a hassle to change this setting every time, since I obviously would like to profit from my fast cellular network when it comes to smaller quantities of data (e.g. navigation or messaging)

Comment: An ap that acts as local VPN server like some ad-filter or firewall software does could also throttle the bandwidth. Technically this should not be a big problem, but I don't know any app that allows to do so.